# simplexml_load_file not parsing correctly

Tags: php

I want to parse the following XML file using **simplexml_load_file** method in PHP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Converter>
<CONFIGURATION>Configuration</CONFIGURATION>
<LogicVariableList>LogicVariableList</LogicVariableList>
<CONVERSION>Conversion</CONVERSION>
<GENERAL>General001
    <Name>SS2</Name>
    <CMPNAME>Kalkitech</CMPNAME>
    <Model>10</Model>
</GENERAL>
</Converter>
```

The method is not returning all the objects under **GENERAL** node its simply returns 'General001' for the key 'GENERAL'. If I removes the text 'General001'  then its works fine.Please let me know how to solve this with out changing the XML structure

Comment: show how did you try that..........

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid XML so SimpleXML can't parse it. You can't have text and tags inside of tag.

You have to wrap `General001` inside of some other tag.

Comment: Thanks for you replay Elon, But this XML is supplied by one external web service, so we can't change this